# What is wrong with this "counterexample" of boundedness of weakly convergent sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, weak-convergence

Weakly convergence sequences $\{u_n\}$ in a Hilbert space $H$ are bounded.

Here is an attempted "counterexample". What is wrong with this?

Let $H = \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$, and let $\{e_n\}$ be the standard basis. Let a sequence $\{u_n\}\subset \ell_2$ be given by
$$ u_n = n^{1/4} e_n. $$
This sequence is not bounded, since $\|u_n\| = n^{1/4}$. But $u_n\to 0$ weakly, as seen as follows: let $v\in \ell_2$ be arbitrary, $v = \sum_k v_k e_k$. Since $\sum_k|v_k|^2<+\infty$, there exists a $C>0$ such that for all $k$, $v_k< Ck^{-1/2}$. Now,
$$ \langle v,u_n\rangle = v_n n^{1/4} < C n^{-1/4} \to 0. $$ 
Thus, $u_n\to 0$ weakly in $\ell_2$.

Comment: existence of $C$ is wrong.

Comment: To give an example: Let $$ v_k = \begin{cases} k^{-1/3} & k \text{ is a third power of an integer}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Comment: I understand: one can say $v_k/\sqrt{k}\to 0$, but not the existence of the $C>0$. Then one cannot conclude that $u_n$ converges weakly.

Comment: @SimenK. No, one cannot conclude  that $v_k/\sqrt{k}\to 0$, either.

Comment: I see that now! Thanks for the answer. In the counterexamples to the decay claim, the intuitive idea is that any (square) summable sequence can be "fleshed out" with zero-strings of increasingly large size, thus slowing down convergence arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in the conclusion $|v_k|<Ck^{-1/2}$. A sequence in $v\in \ell_2$ must tend to $0$, but it can do so arbitrarily slowly. I'll give another  form of martini's example: 
$$
v_k = \begin{cases} 1/n,\quad &\text{ if $k=2^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$} \\ 0 ,\quad &\text{ otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
This sequence is in $\ell_2$ but for every $\epsilon>0$,  $$\limsup_{k\to\infty} k^\epsilon |v_k|=\infty$$